# Are there performance concerns with using the class implements interfaces pattern on API responses in typescript services?

Tags: typescript

The pattern below is something I am seeing more and more in our code base.

Are there any performance concerns with using something like this on API responses that return large data sets?

```
export interface IPerson {
  id: int,
  name: string
}

export class Person implements IPerson{
    id: int;
    name: string;

    constructor(person: any) {
       this.id = person.id;
       this.name = person.name;
    }
}

// usage
let persons: IPerson[] = [];
this.httpClient.get().then(response => {
   const _response = JSON.parse(response) as IPerson[];
    _response.forEach(person => persons.push(new Person(person))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *compilation* performance issues with that code, which means that the only thing that needs to be considered is the JavaScript, which is

```
export class Person {
    constructor(person) {
       this.id = person.id;
       this.name = person.name;
    }
}

let persons = [];
this.httpClient.get().then(response => {
   const _response = JSON.parse(response);
    _response.forEach(person => persons.push(new Person(person))
})
```

Which is quite simple. The only way the above would be a problem would be if

- The Person constructor had expensive code inside it (such as nested loops) - which it doesn't
- Or, if you had an unreasonably large number of items in the response to begin with (like tens of thousands or more - halfway OK computers could handle quite a lot more) - but with that, the issue is more that the response is so huge to begin with, rather than the code here that does stuff with it.

For this code particularly, creating class instances for every object looks very strange. Classes are a decent approach when you want to tie *methods* to *data* together in a single object. If you have only *data*, using just plain objects and arrays usually makes more sense. That is, consider if you could change

```
_response.forEach(person => persons.push(new Person(person))
```

to

```
_response.forEach(({ id, name }) => persons.push({ id, name }))
```

It's also suspicious to be pushing to an outside array inside an asynchronous function, because that often leads some coders to attempt to use the array before it's been populated. Consider if having a Promise that resolves to the array of persons would suit your purposes instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. My example is oversimplified for demonstration purposes, maybe I should revise my question to include a better example and possibly a better question. The implementations I am seeing are specifically in healthcare applications dealing with complex objects such as FHIR responses, patient data, visits etc  There is certainly more complicated logic in the constructor to complete "API like" classification of the data. Ternaries for example. Could this pattern become a "slippery slope" so to speak in terms of performance for end users workstations as this gets adop

Comment: ted and the web app grows in complexity?

Comment: The conditional operator is quite cheap. The only thing you really have to look out for is loops and nested loops. If processing an individual item into the desired schema takes slightly expensive code, then processing all items could be problematic. In such a case, better to have the server do the transformation instead. But this is still unlikely to be an issue. I'd write clean, readable code, and only refactor for performance if it proves to be an issue - anything else is more likely than not to be unnecessary premature optimization.